# How to make a virtual copy of my old computer and turn it to a VPS?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Not sure if this is the correct website to ask this. But I have a HP which I no longer want but want to make a copy of all the files but i want to be able to run it like a VPS runs through an IP, hosted somewhere.

How can I achieve this? Is there a way of making a back up of my computer and turning it into a VPS?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SysInternals disk2vhd.exe works well to capture a live running  system.  You could then run that on aws.amazon.com.